# Partial derivatives of this function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Could someone please confirm for me the partial derivatives of this function: $\dfrac{\mathrm{\partial}L}{\mathrm{\partial}U}$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm{\partial}L}{\mathrm{\partial}V}$:

$L = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{i, j}^{N} \Bigg( \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)^2 + \epsilon^2\Bigg)^\alpha$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are $I_1$ and $I_2$? Just some arbitrary functions?

Comment: Yes, they represent the brightness values of pixels in an image. $I_2$ and $I_1$ are both images, $i$ and $j$ are the locations of the pixels, and $U$ and $V$ are horizontal and vertical displacements.

Comment: I see. So $I$ stands for "Intensity"? Are you trying to find the "optimal fractional shift" of one image so that it best matches another image?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: This doesn't really address your original question, but: If you're willing to restrict yourself to the 2-norm ($\alpha = 1$), I believe this problem can be solved more easily in Fourier space, where a shift by a fraction of a grid spacing can be represented as a multiplication by a complex kernel.

Comment: I'm actually optimising this function and learning $U$ and $V$ using a convolutional neural network and back-propagation. I was curious and wanted to check what the partial derivatives were on paper. My calculus is a bit rusty and I just wanted to check if my calculations were correct.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial U}
&= \dfrac{1}{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial U}\sum_{i, j}^{N} \Bigg( \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)^2 + \epsilon^2\Bigg)^\alpha\\[0.1in]
&=\dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{i, j}^{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial U} \Bigg( \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)^2 + \epsilon^2\Bigg)^\alpha\\[0.1in]
&=\dfrac{\alpha}{N} \sum_{i, j}^{N} \Bigg( \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)^2 + \epsilon^2\Bigg)^{\alpha-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial U}\Bigg( \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)^2 + \epsilon^2\Bigg)\\[0.1in]
&=\dfrac{2\alpha}{N} \sum_{i, j}^{N} \Bigg( \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)^2 + \epsilon^2\Bigg)^{\alpha-1} \Big(I_2(i + U, j + V) - I_1(i, j)\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial U}I_2(i + U, j + V)
\end{align}

The partial derivative with respect to $V$ can be evaluated in exactly the same way.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my answer good sir!